# sp_executeSQL errors in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am attempting to write an SP in SQL Server that takes 4 input parameters and returns the results of a query which will have a WHERE statement based on the parameters. I'm attempting to use sp_executeSql for this but keep getting the following errors:

**Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 61
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 61
Must declare the scalar variable "@p_txnStDate".**

I can't find anything wrong with the syntax (and the `ALTER PROCEDURE` statement executes without issues) and the variable in question is clearly declared:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_adm_rpt_autoBarStatusUpdates] 
    @p_reportType VARCHAR(50),
    @p_attyFName NVARCHAR(20),
    @p_attyLName NVARCHAR(254), 
    @p_txnStDate NVARCHAR(10),
    @p_txnFnDate NVARCHAR(10)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- VARIABLE DECLARATION
    DECLARE @mainQuery AS NVARCHAR(2000)
    DECLARE @whereClause AS VARCHAR(300) 
    DECLARE @paramList AS NVARCHAR(50) 
    DECLARE @attyFName AS NVARCHAR(20)
    DECLARE @attyLName AS NVARCHAR(254)

    SET @whereClause = '' 
    SET @attyFName = UPPER(RTRIM(LTRIM(@p_attyFName)))
    SET @attyLName = UPPER(RTRIM(LTRIM(@p_attyLName)))

-- Dynamically construct the WHERE clause

-- First Name Paramater 
IF (LEN(ISNULL(RTRIM(LTRIM(@p_attyFName)),'')) > 0) 
    SET @whereClause = N'(UPPER(attyinfo.firstname) = @attyFName)'

-- Last Name Paramater 
IF (LEN(ISNULL(RTRIM(LTRIM(@p_attyLName)),'')) > 0)  
BEGIN
    IF (LEN(@whereClause) > 0) 
        SET @whereClause = @whereClause + N' AND (UPPER(attyinfo.lastname) = @attyLName)'
    ELSE
        SET @whereClause = N'(UPPER(attyinfo.lastname) = @attyLName)'
END

-- Dates - Between
IF ((LEN(@p_txnStDate) > 0) AND (LEN(@p_txnFnDate) > 0))
    BEGIN
        IF (LEN(@whereClause) > 0) 
            SET @whereClause = @whereClause + N' AND (status_chg_dt BETWEEN @p_txnStDate AND @p_txnFnDate)'
        ELSE
            SET @whereClause = N'(status_chg_dt BETWEEN @p_txnStDate AND @p_txnFnDate)'
    END
ELSE
    -- Start Date Only
    BEGIN
        IF (LEN(@p_txnStDate) > 0) 
            IF (LEN(@whereClause) > 0) 
                SET @whereClause = @whereClause + N' AND (status_chg_dt >= @p_txnStDate)'
            ELSE
                SET @whereClause = N'(status_chg_dt >= @p_txnStDate)'
    -- Finish Date Only
        ELSE IF (LEN(@p_txnFnDate) > 0) 
            IF (LEN(@whereClause) > 0) 
                SET @whereClause = @whereClause + N' AND (status_chg_dt <= @p_txnFnDate)'
            ELSE SET @whereClause = N'(status_chg_dt <= @p_txnFnDate)'
    END
END

-- Main query without the WHERE clause
SET @mainQuery = 'SELECT attyinfo.prid, attyinfo.personid, attyBarAutoStatusChanges.bm_id, attyBarAutoStatusChanges.pe_id, attyBarAutoStatusChanges.pr_id, CASE LEN(ISNULL(attyinfo.middlename,'''')) WHEN 0 THEN ISNULL(attyinfo.firstname,'''') + '' '' + ISNULL(attyinfo.lastname,'''') ELSE attyinfo.firstname + '' '' + attyinfo.middlename + '' '' + attyinfo.lastname END AS filed_by_atty, attyBarAutoStatusChanges.atty_3293_filed_for AS filed_for_atty, attyBarAutoStatusChanges.case_3293_filed_for AS filed_for_case, attyBarAutoStatusChanges.ltst_3293_filed_dt As filed_date, attyBarAutoStatusChanges.status_chg_dt, attyBarStatusBase.bar_status_init FROM attyinfo INNER JOIN attyBarAutoStatusChanges ON attyinfo.prid = attyBarAutoStatusChanges.pr_id AND attyinfo.personid = attyBarAutoStatusChanges.pe_id INNER JOIN attyBarStatusBase ON attyBarAutoStatusChanges.bm_id = attyBarStatusBase.bm_id AND attyBarAutoStatusChanges.pe_id = attyBarStatusBase.pe_id AND attyBarAutoStatusChanges.pr_id = attyBarStatusBase.pr_id WHERE attyBarAutoStatusChanges.op_code = ''BAR_STAT_AOR_TO_ACTV'''

-- Append WHERE clause (if applicable)
IF (LEN(@whereClause) > 0) 
    SET @mainQuery = @mainQuery + ' AND ' + @whereClause

-- Parameter List
SET @paramList = '@attyFName NVARCHAR, @attyLName NVARCHAR, @txnStDate NVARCHAR, @txnFnDate NVARCHAR'

-- Final Execution
EXEC sp_executesql @mainQuery, @paramList, @attyFName, @attyLName, @p_txnStDate, @p_txnFnDate
```

I'm at a bit of a loss as to why this procedure is failing.  I'm running it simply by issuing the following command:

```
EXEC usp_adm_rpt_autoBarStatusUpdates 'BAR_STAT_AOR_TO_ACTV', 'John', 'Joseph', '1/1/2016', '2/1/2016'
```

Comment: What's with the `**DECLARE @txnStDate...**`? That's not valid syntax, which is why you are getting the error. If you are trying to comment it, use `/*...*/` but seeing as you are actually using `@txnStDate` in your code, you should just remove the `**`.

Comment: fyi: `IF ((LEN(@txnStDate) > 0) AND (LEN(@txnStDate) > 0))` checks the same variable twice, then uses a different variable (`@txnFnDate`).

Comment: @HABO - great catch!  It should be:
((LEN(@txnStDate) > 0) AND (LEN(@txnFnDate) > 0))

Comment: do a PRINT @mainQuery before executing it.

Comment: PRINT gives the following WHERE clause:

**WHERE attyBarAutoStatusChanges.op_code = 'BAR_STAT_AOR_TO_ACTV' AND (UPPER(attyinfo.firstname) = @attyFName) AND (UPPER(attyinfo.lastname) = @attyLName) AND (status_chg_dt BETWEEN @p_txnStDate AND @p_txnFnDate)**

Comment: This is a catch-all type of query and the performance can be pretty challenging. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/ Also you are declaring variables of varchar but no length. And why of why are you using varchar to hold dates???

Comment: you are using @ p_txnFnDate in your query but this is not in the @ paramlist

Answer (score 0):

Why sp_executesql and not directly SELECT?

Try something like this

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_adm_rpt_autoBarStatusUpdates] 
    @p_reportType VARCHAR(50),
    @p_attyFName NVARCHAR(20) = NULL,
    @p_attyLName NVARCHAR(254) = NULL, 
    @p_txnStDate NVARCHAR(10) = NULL,
    @p_txnFnDate NVARCHAR(10) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET DATEFORMAT dmy;

    DECLARE @attyFName AS NVARCHAR(20) = UPPER(RTRIM(LTRIM(@p_attyFName)))
    DECLARE @attyLName AS NVARCHAR(254) = UPPER(RTRIM(LTRIM(@p_attyLName))) 
    DECLARE @txnStDate DATE = @p_txnStDate
    DECLARE @txnFnDate DATE = @p_txnFnDate

    SELECT      attyinfo.prid,
                attyinfo.personid,
                attyBarAutoStatusChanges.bm_id,
                attyBarAutoStatusChanges.pe_id,
                attyBarAutoStatusChanges.pr_id,
                CASE LEN(ISNULL(attyinfo.middlename,''''))
                WHEN 0 THEN ISNULL(attyinfo.firstname,'''') + '' '' + ISNULL(attyinfo.lastname,'''')
                ELSE attyinfo.firstname + '' '' + attyinfo.middlename + '' '' + attyinfo.lastname
                END AS filed_by_atty,
                attyBarAutoStatusChanges.atty_3293_filed_for AS filed_for_atty,
                attyBarAutoStatusChanges.case_3293_filed_for AS filed_for_case,
                attyBarAutoStatusChanges.ltst_3293_filed_dt As filed_date,
                attyBarAutoStatusChanges.status_chg_dt,
                attyBarStatusBase.bar_status_init
    FROM        attyinfo
    INNER JOIN  attyBarAutoStatusChanges
    ON          attyinfo.prid = attyBarAutoStatusChanges.pr_id
    AND         attyinfo.personid =     attyBarAutoStatusChanges.pe_id
    INNER JOIN  attyBarStatusBase
    ON          attyBarAutoStatusChanges.bm_id = attyBarStatusBase.bm_id
    AND         attyBarAutoStatusChanges.pe_id = attyBarStatusBase.pe_id
    AND         attyBarAutoStatusChanges.pr_id = attyBarStatusBase.pr_id
    WHERE       attyBarAutoStatusChanges.op_code = 'BAR_STAT_AOR_TO_ACTV'

    AND         (
                (
                UPPER(attyinfo.firstname) = @attyFName
    AND         @attyFName IS NOT NULL
    AND         @attyFName <> ''
                )
    OR          @attyFName IS NULL
    OR          @attyFName = ''
                )

    AND         (
                (
                UPPER(attyinfo.lastname) = @attyLName
    AND         @attyLName IS NOT NULL
    AND         @attyLName <> ''
                )
    OR          @attyLName IS NULL
    OR          @attyLName = ''
                )

    AND         (
                (
                status_chg_dt >= @txnStDate
    AND         @txnStDate IS NOT NULL
                )
    OR          @txnStDate IS NULL
                )

    AND         (
                (
                status_chg_dt <= @txnFnDate
    AND         @txnFnDate IS NOT NULL
                )
    OR          @txnFnDate IS NULL
                )

    RETURN 1
END
```

The logic is very simple:

If Value IS NOT NULL then compare with column... else (If Value IS NULL) then NOT compare...

Comment: You should read this article for how to make this type of query faster. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/

Comment: Good article... Thanks!